# How to fix problem of CORS with fetch request for POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch-api

I have problem with request POST in fetch function. I make REST API with react and PHP and I get error Access-Control-Allow-Origin is required. I have this header in my web API. This is my code (begin) in PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: access-control-allow-origin");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

and in React:

```
//method = POST
//body = {"name":"test","body":"test"}
const apiCall = (url, method, body, resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(resp => {
        if(resp.ok) {
            resp.json().then(json => resolve(json));
        }
        else {
            reject(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

I try to communicate with other server and API - result was the same.
Screen with error in Google Chrome browser:

[image: screen]

Please help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to add the CORS MODULE and Proxy in Server.